# Cron Linux не выполняется файл

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

устанавливаю крон через `sudo crontab -e -u www-data` такую запись `0 10 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php`

Если посмотреть лог то скрип запускается, но код не выполняется, но если запустить из консоли в ручную `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php`, то он отрабатывает

Куда копать ?

Comment: вручную запускаешь от `www-data`? относительные пути в скриптах как-то используются? переменные скрипты как-то используются? как именно ты определяешь, что «скрип запускается» и что «код не выполняется»?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить ведение логов как-то так:

```
0 10 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php >>/var/log/test.log
```

Чтобы точно убедиться что скрипт не запускается. Но думается что ошибка таки в самом скрипте (не хватает прав, не абсолютные пути и т.п.)

Comment: Тогда и stderr перевести в лог `2>&1` в конце команды дописать